# C++ - lite databases compiled into binary

Tags: c++, database, nosql

Please, suggest some lite databases to store key-value data (and maybe some other useful features). Something like NoSQL.

The main requirement that this databases must compile with my C++ program (into my binary) and no additional process on the system.

Comment: Even though its not NoSQL I'd still recommend SQLite: http://www.sqlite.org/ - it would be easy to create a wrapper emulating a key-value storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If SQLite isn't suitable, some better-known in-process key/value stores are:

- [Berkeley DB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB)
- [Kyoto Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/)
- [LevelDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LevelDB)

Note that for Berkeley Db and Kyoto Cabinet you'll probably need to buy a commercial license.

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider SQLite? It's a library which can be statically compiled into your code. You store the database as a file in the filesystem. 
https://www.sqlite.org/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Others have already mentioned SQLite, which I'd also recommend since it's so easy to use. It's extremely lightweight too despite using SQL as a front end.

Another nice embedded* database is [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/overview/index.html). It better fits your request than SQLite (it's key/value DB) but the learning curve is much steeper. Now, *I* tend to be wary of open-source Oracle products (they have a bad track record managing the FLOSS projects they acquire, to say the least) but it's still worth mentioning, if you have no prejudice against Oracle it's quite a good product in itself.

(*) By the way, in order to help you find more products like that, the keywords you want to use for searching on the web are *embedded database* or *in-process database*.

Comment: thanks for suggestion and keywords :) english is not my native language and time to time its very hard to found something specific

Comment: @abrahab I'm not a native English speaker either so I understand perfectly, which is the very reason why I help with keywords whenever I know them. ;) Good luck.